# fullPage.js moving to next slide, moving all the other slides from other sections together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have already set everything from this issue here:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/200

But I only can get this to work for the section 1, slide 0 to the right. I have 9 slides in each of the 2 sections in my page. I would like to get this working for everyone of them, to the right and to the left. (the section 2 slides changing along with the section 1 slides change).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same number of slides in each section?

Comment: yes. 3 in each section